# How to create a stored procedure with given data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014-express

I want to create a stored procedure in SQL Server with the given data below, but I don't know how to achieve this. My requirement is to change status column to overdue when rate column is not equal one hundred and end date is expired.

```
if (Rate == 100)
    Status = "Completed"
else if (Rate != 100 && EndDate < Today) //when end date expired and rate is not equal 100
    Status = "Overdue"
else
    Status = "Not started" //rate equal 0 and end date is intact
```

Expected output: `Tasking` table:

| Task Id | Task Name | Start Date | End Date | Rate(%) | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Digging | 2/16/2024 | 2/17/2024 | 25 | Overdue |
| 2 | Cleaning | 2/19/2024 | 2/20/2024 | 30 | In progress |
| 3 | Planting | 2/19/2024 | 2/19/2024 | 100 | Completed |
| 4 | Planting | 2/22/2024 | 2/22/2024 | 0 | Not started |

Comment: Have you considered using a `CASE` expression? I'm  not sure how a procedure is involved here, if I am honest.

Comment: Side note, 2014 is about to reach EoL. As you're on Express you really don't have a *good* reason why you shouldn't be using a more recent version; Express is free to use in production environments and upgrading [the database engine] therefore doesn't "cost" anything.

Comment: I don't know how to Case expression for this

Comment: Perhaps a read of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) is in order then.

Comment: _My requirement is to change status column_ I believe you can do this with an UPDATE statement. Why do you need a stored procedure?

Comment: @Abra Yes l know about that. I'm exploring other options, I want to know if it's possible for a store procedure to display the expected output so that it would be easier to fetch and display on card via angular

Comment: You seem to confuse two things: how to get your conditions to calculate (use `CASE`) and how to save a set of statements or queries to be executed (create a procedure). These are two separate things. And both are fully documented.

Comment: If you are amending an existing table - have you considered computed column ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver16)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the [Case expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)?

Try something like

```
SELECT TaskId, TaskName, StartDate, EndDate, Rate,
CASE
   WHEN Rate = 100 THEN 'Completed'
   WHEN Rate < 100 AND EndDate < GETUTCDATE() THEN 'Overdue'
   WHEN Rate < 100 AND EndDate >= GETUTCDATE() THEN 'In progress'
   ELSE 'Not started'
END as status

FROM Data
```

Comment: `CASE` ***expression*** *.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateStatus
    @id int,
    @rate int,
    @endDate date,
    @status varchar(20) 
AS
BEGIN
        if(@rate = 100) 
        set @status = 'Completed'
        if(@rate != 100 and @endDate < GETDATE()) 
        set @status = 'Overdue'
        else
        set @status = 'Not started'
        UPDATE tablename set columnname= @status where id = @id;
END
```

Comment: @status shouldn't be a parameter to the procedure in my opinion

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**